# Macbook trackpad scroll speed

Tags: touchpad, macbook

Recently installed Ubuntu 22.04.1 om my Macbook Pro 2013, and I cannot get the scroll speed on the trackpad sorted out. It's currently insanely fast - unusable. I've tried to check every possible solution on the web, but cannot get it to work - there is very little out there about specifically doing this on a macbook's trackpad.
Anybody have a possible solution?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Have you tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/255890/how-can-i-adjust-the-mouse-scroll-speed)?

Comment: I believe that that is regarding a mouse only - right? I

Comment: No, Sir. Actually, the system doesn't know or care it is a mouse or a trackpad as the same as coffee and tea. I mean, it knows but only a name. I can change trackpad/trackball sensitivity with `xinput`. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1289969/restore-apple-magic-trackpad-2-settings-on-ubuntu